# Rotating two vectors to another plane

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, physics, mathematical-physics, rotations

I have four vectors $A$, $B$, $A'$, and $B'$. Now $A$ and $B$ are in one plane and  $A'$ and $B'$ are in another plane.
      Now is there any way so that I can get the components of $A'$ in the same direction of  $A$ or $B$. Similarly, the components of $B'$ in the same direction of  $A$ or $B$.

Thanks in advance,

BK

Comment: What sort of solution are you looking for? A transformation matrix? Or something else?

Comment: @werenard...a transformation matrix will also work...I am trying to program it ...I know components of A, B, A', and B'...

Comment: wouldn't projection work?

Comment: Maybe this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2647763/work-out-the-a-rotation-matrix-in-this-condition will help you.. anyway normalize vectors to unit length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally if you know that for two **not collinear** vectors $a'=Ra$ and $b'=Rb$ you know also that $R(a \times b)= a' \times b'$ ( $\times$ here  vector product and $R$ rotation matrix)

These six vectors are sufficient to construct from them two $3 \times 3$ matrices with vectors as columns, name them $C=[a \ \ b \ \ a\times b]$ and $C'=[a'  \ \ b'  \ \ a' \times b' ]$.

So we have $C'=RC$.

From this we can calculate rotation matrix $R$.

$R=C'C^{-1}$

$C^{-1}$ exists because $a,  b,  a\times b$ are not coplanar.

Comment: Of course I'm assuming here that $a$ and $a'$ have equal length ( if not they should by normalized to, for example, unit length). The same for $b$ and $b'$ . Also the angle between $a$ and $b$ should be the same as the angle between $a'$ and $b'$.

Comment: ok...I will do that...Thanks

Comment: @ Widawensen....if the angle between a and b is not same as the angle between a′ and b′. In that case is there any way out?

Comment: @Bikash Not by rotation. However you can try to obtain approximate result if you take a, a' and components orthogonal of b and b' to appropriately a and a'.. name them $b_p$ and $b'_p$. Then they should be used in formula for matrices $C$ and $C'$, however you agree by that then that only these orthogonal components of b and b' would be matched

Comment: @Bikash  Component of $b$ orthogonal to $a$ can be obtained with formula $b_p=(1-aa^T)b$ assuming $a$ is normalized to unit length... working with $a,b_p$ and $ a\times b_p$ you have guarantee of good angles (all are $90^\circ$) between these vectors, suitable for finding the rotation..

Comment: @ Widawensen..Thanks. However in my case both the angles are same...therefore I can directly use the rotation matrix ...

Comment: @Bikash Sometimes in **experimental** data some inaccuracies can occur then it is a good thing   also to normalize the angles between vectors..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74878/discussion-between-bikash-and-widawensen).